# Generating table name dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a query where the table name is generated dynamically based on some parameter. I am not able to figure out a way to do this.

Comment: which application/db-client do you use to run the query?

Comment: I am using oracle and what I was trying something like             "select name from  dev1name.devname and exists
(select 'devicelocationview' as devname from dual) dev1name"   but I know this is not correct

Answer (score 2):

Look at dynamic SQL as detailed in the documentation.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm#26799

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exact requirements you have (and I know that joining a sys table might not be a good idea), but you can use the query below to get the list of all tables-

```
select owner, table_name 
  from all_tables;
```

As a note the query `all_tables` table consists of the `column_name` as well.